# Ubuntu Linux Mono Errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono

I'm getting alot of errors. I'm getting these errors while trying to compile my program using the DMCS compiler. Any help is appreciated!

The command:

```
 dmcs -recurse:'*/*.cs' -r:mysql.data.dll -r:Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

These are errors:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Path is invalid
Parameter name: path
  at System.IO.Directory.ValidateDirectoryListing (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.Boolean& stop) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, FileAttributes mask, FileAttributes attrs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path, System.String searchPattern) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.ProcessSourceFiles (System.String spec, Boolean recurse) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.CSCParseOption (System.String option, System.String[]& args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.ParseArguments (System.String[] args, Boolean require_files, System.Func`3 unknown_option_parser) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Create (System.String[] args, Boolean require_files, System.Func`3 unknown_option_parser, Mono.CSharp.ReportPrinter printer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: Path is invalid
Parameter name: path
  at System.IO.Directory.ValidateDirectoryListing (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.Boolean& stop) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, FileAttributes mask, FileAttributes attrs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path, System.String searchPattern) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.ProcessSourceFiles (System.String spec, Boolean recurse) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.CSCParseOption (System.String option, System.String[]& args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.ParseArguments (System.String[] args, Boolean require_files, System.Func`3 unknown_option_parser) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Create (System.String[] args, Boolean require_files, System.Func`3 unknown_option_parser, Mono.CSharp.ReportPrinter printer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your compiler don't understand the `-recurse`. Try to get that expanded by the invoking shell:

```
  dmcs **/*.cs -r:mysql.data.dll -r:Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

might work with a recent `bash` (version 4) or a `zsh`; otherwise try

```
  dmcs $(find -type f -name '*.cs') \
     -r:mysql.data.dll -r:Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```